# Paroled into the US for signoff from ship and applying for an F1 Visa. How should I go through this?

Tags: usa

Last year, I was paroled into US at Houston port in order to signoff from my vessel. I was accompanied from the vessel to the airport to catch my flight on the same day. It shows ‘DT’ under my class of admission on my i94. I also have stamp of paroled with ‘DT-Repat’ written on my passport.

I was working as a marine engineer and have travelled to US more than 10 times for my job but haven't got the chance to go back to US because of a different trade right now.

I have an active C1/D visa and I will be applying for a new F1 Visa to study at Duke University and also would like to apply F2 for my spouse.
Will this cause any issue in order to get my student visa? And if no, can I get an interview waiver? How can I explain the stamp on my passport?

What should I put into the DS 160 for whether i was refused to enter the USA?

Comment: Being paroled is not a refusal of entry. As you entered the US, even though you were escorted

Comment: @NicolasFormichella someone who has been paroled into the US has not been "admitted" to the US, however.